# MS Access EndTime AfterUpdate Macro

Tags: database, ms-access, macros

I have MS Access 2013. I'm working on a Database with Tables : Games and Events. In my Events table I need the EventEndTime to be the EventStartTime + Games.GameDuration.

I tried using the AfterUpdates Macro but it didn't work. The field comes out empty.

I tested it out with DateAdd to just add 3 hours first but it doesn't work.
[The AfterUpdate Macro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLMaT.png)

Comment: What type of field is `GameDuration`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `GameDuration` is an integer that represents hours:

```
EventEndTime=DateAdd("h",GameDuration,EventStartTime)
```

If `GameDuration` is a Date/Time field that has hours and minutes:

```
EventEndTime=DateAdd("n",Minute(GameDuration),DateAdd("h",Hour(GameDuration),EventStartTime))
```

Comment: GameDuration is a simple integer. Sorry for asking a stupid question, but where do I put the code?

Comment: That really depends on the rest of your application and what triggers the update. If you just want to update pre-existing data, then you would have to create an UPDATE query and use the code there.

Comment: What if I want it to automatically populate it based on those 2 information? I read that Default Value would not be suitable for it.

Comment: Default value only applies when the record is created. In order to do anything "automatically" you need to identify the trigger under which the automated process occurs, then attach code to that trigger. The code may be VBA, Access SQL or a GUI generated query. It depends on what your trigger is. The DateAdd function woks with all of them (except you have to use single quotes if it is Access SQL). It looks like the AfterUpdate event that you tried to use is the right place for you.

Comment: Keep in mind that you will not be able to update form fields if the data source is linked tables unless you set "Inconsistent Updates"

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Many thanks for all the help